# How to extract data from an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I have an Angular based application that is making a RESTful request to a server whose response is a JSON stream that represents a list of objects of the following type:

```
export interface Personal {
  theAddress: string;
  theCity: string;
  theState: String;
  theCountry: string;
  emailAddress: string;
}
```

The code within my component uses an HttpClient GET request to get data to place into an Observable:

```
people$: Observable<Personal[]>;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.people$ = this.http
        .get<Personal[]>("/people/get")
        .map(data => _.values(data))
        .do(console.log);
}
```

For various reasons, I would like to extract the contents of the Observable and put them into an array of people objects. After reading various documentation on the Internet, I am aware that to extract the data received I need to somehow use a subscribe method on the Observable. Unfortunately, it is unclear to me exactly how to do this.

Can someone help with this? How does one extract the objects received by an Observable into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the values in an array, you don't need `people$` to be an observable. Just do this:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

people: Personal[];

...

ngOnInit() {
  // Let's get rid of lodash for the mapping thing
  this.http.get<Map<string, Personal>>('/people/get')
    .map(data => Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]))
    .subscribe((people: Personal[]) => this.people = people);
}
```

BTW you seem to be using an out-of-date `rxjs` library (previous to version 5.5). If you update it you'll have to use pipeable operators:

```js
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

...
people: Personal[];

...

ngOnInit() {
  // Let's get rid of lodash for the mapping thing
  this.http.get<Map<string, Personal>>('/people/get')
    .pipe(map(data => Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])))
    .subscribe((people: Personal[]) => this.people = people);
}
```

As an additional observation, as you're using a lodash function to convert objects to array. Apparently `this.http.get<Personal[]>` isn't really returning an array of `Personal`, but an object, so you'll probably have to write the `get` method like this (like I did on the above code):

```js
this.http.get<{[id: string]: Personal}>
```

or

```js
this.http.get<Map<string, Personal>>
```

Comment: Getting a strange error when using this answer: the compiler is saying that it "cannot find map" in the observable. This happens in both the old and updated rxjs library. Am I missing something in the declaration?

Comment: I'll make some addings to the answer concerning the imports you should be using for rxjs (current and old versions)

Comment: The additional import seems to have fixed the map problem. Now it is complaining about not being able to find "_". I am still learning the fine points of Typescript. Does "_" also need an import?

Comment: Just use single quotes instead. The problem here is that there is more that one representation for double-quotes. The wrong double-quotes representation can happen if you copy-and-paste code from elsewhere, like from Stackoverflow.

Comment: OOPS: I didn't use quotes in code. The exact syntax I used in the code (using updated rxjs) is: .pipe(map(data => _.values(data))) The compiler is complaining about the _.  Sorry for the misrepresentation...

Comment: Oh, so make sure that you're importing lodash... but if I was you, I'd use regular javascript for getting those values out of the HTTP call returned object. I'm gonna update the answer once more.

Comment: As a final comment, make sure of what kind of answer you're getting from your backend API. If it's already an array, you can strip out all that `map` part of the code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to subscribe to the observable by calling `.subscribe` on it and pass a callback to `subscribe`. Inside this callback you will receive data from observable via callback parameters and than you can assign this data to local variable. see the code below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.people$ = this.http
        .get<Personal[]>("/people/get")
        .map(data => _.values(data))
        .do(console.log)
        .subscribe(data => this.someArray = data); // ==> see this line
}
```

The observable returned from the angular `http.get` are cold observable. They are not executed until you subscribe to them.